# Deprecated method is confusing

Tags: android, android-fragments, deprecated, android-listfragment

I'm confused about the use of a deprecated method, I'm using a class that extends of **ListFragment** class and I'm implementing the **onAttach()** method, that method has two "versions"

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    //This method requires api level 23 or higher
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    //This method was deprecated in API level 23.
}
```

I've read about deprecated methods and I understand that it'll be deleted in future releases then I've decided to use **onAttach(Context context)** but now I'm confused for two reasons:

1- If I want to do an application with minsdkversion 8 and targetsdkversion 24 what method I should implement?

2-I'm doing an app with minsdkversion 8 and I used the **onAttach(Context context)** method and it works in an emulator with api 8 and I tried in a smartphone with api 16 and It works too, Why it works? perhaps It should work only in version 23 and higher...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Support Library ListFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html), then you can use `onAttach(Context)` on all API 4+ devices. If you are using the [framework ListFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), then the `onAttach(Context)` method *will* fail on pre-API 23 devices as it does not exist.

I suspect since you've confirmed that `onAttach(Context)` works on older API levels, you are already using the Support Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

> 1- If I want to do an application with minsdkversion 8 and targetsdkversion 24 what method I should implement?

Always use the non-deprecated method. Android programmers took care that it is backwards compatible.

> 2-I'm doing an app with minsdkversion 8 and I used the onAttach(Context context) method and it works in an emulator with api 8 and I tried in a smartphone with api 16 and It works too, Why it works? perhaps It should work only in version 23 and higher...?

The most obvious reason is probably backwards compatibility and that a
`Context` is a wider entity than an `Activity`. This is because `Activity` implements the `Context` interface, thus wherever the `Context` is needed, you can instead provide an `Activity`. This is probably the reason why using the version with `Context` works on lower APIs.

As for the method deprecation, the reasoning behind this is probably that one day Fragments may not be limited to being attached to activities only (just a wild guess), and having the method take a Context argument is the first step towards that.

Comment: Fragments are already not tied to an Activity - see [FragmentController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentController.html) and [FragmentHostCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentHostCallback.html). Currently Activities are the only ones that implement it in the Android API though.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake for clarifying it. I had not known this, I just had an accurate hunch, so it seems :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not answer your question but I stop using `onAttach()` to get the reference to the calling Activity...

I noticed that I was holding an reference to the Activity but I use it in very few places...

So, I started to call `getActivity()` when I need an reference to calling activity... This way, you dont need to override `onAttach()`